# How do i make the gradient effect adaptable with background image in CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, opacity, linear-gradients

Can someone provide me a source to achieve this type of gradient with background movie image in css. I can create gradients but the thing is i just want to know how do i make it adoptable with the background movie image. Please check image for reference .

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not a gradient. That text container might be using a property `backdrop-filter: blur(150px)` (adjust the pixels to your liking)
Backdrop filter pretty much applies a filter to the background of your element, in this case, I'm using blur() to get that effect.If you do not get the desired blurred background, you can set the `background-color` of your element to `rgba(18, 22, 32, 0.6)` an play around with the alpha value (the last one)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. It helped and gave me a direction.